# Trying to create a PWA using .net 7 Mvc but getting ArgumentNullException Parameter Path value cannot be null

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, progressive-web-apps

I have created the PWA application as stated in the Microsoft documentation By adding the nu get package WebEssentials.AspNetCore.PWA then I created a manifest.json with the relevant fields

I also added the referenced images into the images folder

manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "PWADemo",
  "short_name": "PWA",
  "description": "Demo PWA application in ASP.NET Core.",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "/images/icon 192x192.png",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "/images/icon 512x512.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "512x512"
    }
  ],
  "display": "standalone",
  "start_url": "/"
}
```

I then added it to the program.cs IServiceCollection

Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddMvc();

builder.Services.AddProgressiveWebApp(new PwaOptions { RegisterServiceWorker = true });
```

When I run the application I get this error screen

[image]

I am not sure what I need to change in order for this to work

Answer (score 0):

Oh its manifest.json file path issue, (Make sure no white space in image src)
1- Make sure you put the **json** file in **wwwroot** folder.
2- Images folder should also in **wwwroot** folder